# Wrong results with Russian stemmer

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7

I have index `products` with these analyzer settings. Search with query `стекло` returns empty result but with query `стеклоы` it works well.

```
PUT /products
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "russian_stop": {
          "type": "stop",
          "stopwords": "_russian_" 
        },
        "russian_stemmer": {
          "type": "stemmer",
          "language": "russian"
        },
        "russian_synonym": {
          "type": "synonym",
          "synonyms": [
            "айфон => iphone",
            "хонор => honor"
          ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "ru_en": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "russian_stop",
            "russian_stemmer",
            "russian_synonym"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

GET /products/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "стекло",
            "operator": "and",
            "analyzer": "ru_en",
            "fuzziness": 0, 
            "fields": [
              "name",
              "category"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to index settings these mapping

```
"mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "ru_en"
      }
    }
  }
```